# Powershell - Enable 'Directory Browsing' on Physical Folder in IIS6

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I need a powershell script to enable 'Directory Browsing' on a physical folder in IIS6.  The key is that the folder I would like to modify is a subfolder of another physical folder.  Neither folder is a "virtual directory".

I tried the following, but the DirectoryEntry is empty.  I assume that's because the folder is not a "virtual directory" .

```
$oDir = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/Test/Upgrade")

# Loop thru all even though there should only be one...
foreach ($oDirEntry in $oDir)
{
   Write-Host "Enabling Directory Browsing on IIS folder [" $oDirEntry.Name "]."
   $oDirEntry.put("EnableDirBrowsing",$true)
   $oDirEntry.psbase.CommitChanges()        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest code ever written, but I tried many different iterations and this is the one that works...

```
$sFolderName = "Test"
$sSubFolderName = "SubTest"
$oSubFolder = $null

# Get reference to root website
$oService = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root")

foreach ($oChild in $oService.children)
{
    if ($oChild.Name -eq $sFolderName)
    {
        # Check if we already have an IIsWebDirectory named $sSubFolderName
        foreach ($oChild2 in $oChild.children)
        {
            if ($oChild2.Name -eq $sSubFolderName)
            {
                $oSubFolder = $oChild2
            }
        }

        # Create one if it doesn't exist
        if ($oSubFolder -eq $null)
        {
            $oSubFolder = $oChild.Children.Add($sSubFolderName, "IIsWebDirectory")
            $oSubFolder.psbase.CommitChanges()
        }

        $oSubFolder.Put("AccessRead",$true)
        $oSubFolder.Put("EnableDirBrowsing",$true)
        $oSubFolder.psbase.CommitChanges()      
    }
}
```